# Azure AD change tenant settings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Looking through the Graph API at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/traverse_the_graph and can't seem to find the ability to Get/Set some of the more high level settings available in the Azure Portal and a programmatic fashion. Some of these include:

- Changing branding - Sign-in page image
- User Settings - "Members can invite"

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, both Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph REST doesn't' support this function. If you have any ideas or feedback about the Microsoft Graph REST, you can submit it from link [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).